# Is there an R function that reads a specific value and move to the next column?

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

I would like to know if R could read a specific value by column in the matrix (the value will only read one specific value (more than x) before moving to the next column). This values can only be acknowledged once before moving to the next column.

Illustration

```
          C1  C2  C3

R1        (10,15*,5)

R2        (20*,10,5)

R3        (5,10,20*)
```

Values of 15 and above will be considered once based on column.

Expected outcome:

```
[1] 20, 15, 20
```

Thanks for the support!

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Hi Darren, I would like if the output of 20,15 and 20 is shown in the R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code can find values until the first occurrence of a value `>=` 15 by each column.

```
apply(m, 2, function(x) x[1:which.max(x >= 15)])

# [[1]]
# [1] 10 20
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 15
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  5  5 20
```

If you want the first value which `>=` 15, then

```
apply(m, 2, function(x) x[which.max(x >= 15)])

# [1] 20 15 20
```

---

***Data***

```
m <- matrix(c(10, 20, 5, 15, 10, 10, 5, 5, 20), 3)
```

Comment: I seem to receive an error message  "Error: unexpected '[[' in "[[""

Comment: I made a typo earlier, the code is running now. Greatly appreciate Darren!

Comment: Hey Darren, can I apply this code to a 5 x 5 matrix to obtain a similar result? What happens if there are two values which are greater than 15 and we want to select based on the column independently (The selected values will move to a different row from the previous row). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fincoder07 of course you can use my code on matrices of any dimension. As for your second question, can you provide the example data and expected output?

Comment: Hey Darren, this is an example data and the expected output will be 16*,17*,18*,19*,10*+10*       

            Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4  Col5
Row1        16*   12     16     6    8
Row2        16    10      8    17   10*
Row3        12    13     18*    9   17
Row4        13     7     12    19*  15
Row5        7     17*    15    15   13
Row6        14     3     10     6   10*

Sum         16    17     18    19   20
 
Col 5 will use the sum of Row 2 and Row 6 to exceed the value of 15 (20)

Comment: @Fincoder07 sorry I don't understand your rule. And your new question is almost different from the original one. It's better to post a new question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max.col` after transposing the data and create a row/column matrix to subset data from each column. Using @Darren's data :

```
m[cbind(max.col(t(m) >= 15, ties.method = 'first'), 1:ncol(m))]
#[1] 20 15 20
```

Read about `ties.method` in `?max.col` to know how to handle ties.